# Parsing recordset in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, node.js

I'm trying to display a live dashboard using Google Charts on my `localhost` webpage, harvesting data from an SQL Server table.
I successfully connected to the DB and displayed the data on `localhost`.

Where I'm stuck is, in order to draw the pie chart in Google Charts, I need to take the 4 integers I receive from the DB query and make them a percentage.
My issue is parsing the DB response so I can access each integer individually.

My response in `localhost` looks like this:

```
 {
"recordsets": [
[
{
"Braking_Events": 1441,
"Acceleration_Events": 2480,
"Cornering_Events": 1270,
"Speeding_Events": 2863
}
]
],
"recordset": [
{
"Braking_Events": 1441,
"Acceleration_Events": 2480,
"Cornering_Events": 1270,
"Speeding_Events": 2863
}
],
"output": {},
"rowsAffected": [
1
]
}
```

I am trying to access

```
"Braking_Events": 1441,
"Acceleration_Events": 2480,
"Cornering_Events": 1270,
"Speeding_Events": 2863
```

and set them to JavaScript variables, manipulate them into a percentage and stick them into

```
 function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Braking_Events', 1441],
      ['Acceleration_Events',     2480],
      ['Cornering_Events',      1270],
      ['Speeding_Events',  22863]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Safety Distribution'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: @NinaScholz, no, i don't need both, no sure why they show up since I'm sending the `recordset` only once in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the keys of the object and map a new array for the key and value parts.

```js
var data = { recordsets: [[{ Braking_Events: 1441, Acceleration_Events: 2480, Cornering_Events: 1270, Speeding_Events: 2863 }]], recordset: [{ Braking_Events: 1441, Acceleration_Events: 2480, Cornering_Events: 1270, Speeding_Events: 2863 }], output: {}, rowsAffected: [1] },
    result = Object.keys(data.recordset[0]).map(function (k) {
        return [k, data.recordset[0][k]];
    });


console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```